# Problem when I start my project with wildfly

Tags: java, web-services, wildfly

When I try to start my project with WildFly, I have this error message :

```
11:25:02,066 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."vip.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."vip.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "vip.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.as.connector@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ds.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:194)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:120)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ds.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:90)
    ... 9 more

11:25:02,144 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "vip.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"vip.war\".PARSE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"vip.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
    Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource"}}
11:25:02,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "vip.war" (runtime-name : "vip.war")
11:25:02,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."vip.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "vip.war"

11:25:02,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
11:25:02,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:25:02,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:25:02,285 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 16.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 8.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 13658ms - Started 316 of 543 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 325 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Maybe the problem is beacause an element is missing somewhere ?
Someone can explain me how i can solve it please ?

Comment: `Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource` . I think this is your problem. You set in standalone.xml a datasource. And it not worknig. Try to start wildfly without deployment to solve to the problem with datasource. Then try with `vip.war`

Comment: Did you trying to migrate the project? Because it is not valid datasource configuration for wildfly. This configuration like a JBoss 4/5/6 Datasource configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 

When I start the server wildfly without deployment it work but with vip.war he doesn't work.

I have the same project in on a JBoss 6 server and I took some jsp et class of this project that I integrated in the new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All configuration is wrong. You need re-design datasource configuration. Because your configuration can working with JBoss 6 not Wildfly 16.

[This tutorial](https://cleanprogrammer.net/how-to-configure-datasource-in-wildfly/) will help you create datasource. And [this page](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/migrate-jboss-datasources-howto) show how to migrate datasource from JBoss6 to Wildfly or JBoss AS 7.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Thank you very much !